# Dedup array and sort array by most frequent occurrence (with LoDash)

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, collections, lodash

Say I have an array that goes something like:

```
fruit_basket = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'banana']
```

I want to make an array `fruits` that consists of the fruits found in `fruit basket`, sorted in order of most frequently occurring fruit. (If there are ties I don't care about ordering.)

So one valid value for `fruits` is:

```
['banana', 'orange', 'apple', 'pear']
```

What's the most concise way to achieve this using LoDash? I don't care about run time performance.

Comment: Is pure `js` solution an option ?

Comment: @guest271314 If it is more concise than the lodash solution, then I don't see why not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you'd count the occurences

```
var x = _.chain(fruit_basket).countBy(); // {apple: 1, orange: 1, banana: 2, pear: 1}
```

Then you'd pair them and sort by the number of occurences, using `reverse` to get the largest number first

```
var y = x.toPairs().sortBy(1).reverse(); //[["banana",2],["pear",1],["orange",1],["apple",1]]
```

Then you'd just map back the keys, and get the value as an array

```
var arr = y.map(0).value(); // ['banana', 'orange', 'apple', 'pear']
```

All chained together, it looks like

```
var arr = _.chain(fruit_basket).countBy().toPairs().sortBy(1).reverse().map(0).value();
```

---

Without loDash, something like this would do it

```
var fruit_basket = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'banana'];

var o = {};
fruit_basket.forEach(function(item) {
    item in o ? o[item] += 1 : o[item] = 1;
});
var arr = Object.keys(o).sort(function(a, b) {
    return o[a] < o[b];
});
```

Comment: by passing `1` to `sortBy`, is that saying to sort by the value at the array index `1`?  (I don't see that short hand mentioned in the docs)

Comment: Yes, the syntax is `_.sortBy(list, iteratee, [context])`, but as it's chained the list is passed as `this` and the iteratee is the first argument, here being `1`, meaning `arr[1]` in the inner arrays

Comment: Have you tested that lo dash solution? I don't think it works in the latest version. I'm pretty sure you need to swap out `pairs` for `toPairs` and when I tried to pass the index to `sortBy()` it didn't work correctly...

Comment: @LukeP - I did test it, in jsFiddle which only supports LoDash 2.2.1. Updated the answer to use the new methods available in version 4+

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on this.

It doesn't use lodash as the question asks for. It's a vanilla alternative. I feel this could be valuable to people who land here from Google and don't want to use lodash (that's how I got here, at least).

```
const orderByCountAndDedupe = arr => {
    const counts = new Map();

    arr.forEach( item => {
        if ( !counts.has(item) ) {
            counts.set(item, 1);
        } else {
            counts.set(item, counts.get(item)+1);
        }
    });

    return (
        Array.from(counts)
            .sort( (a, b) => b[1] - a[1])
            .map( ([originalItem, count]) => originalItem)
    );
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

An approach using `for` loop `Array.prototype.splice()`

```js
var fruit_basket = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'pear', 'banana'];
var res = [];
for (var i = 0; i < fruit_basket.length; i++) {
  var index = res.indexOf(fruit_basket[i]);
  // if current item does not exist in `res`
  // push current item to `res`
  if (index == -1) {
    res.push(fruit_basket[i])
  } else {
    // else remove current item , set current item at index `0` of `res`
    res.splice(index, 1);
    res.splice(0, 0, fruit_basket[i])
  }
}

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count occurences using _.countBy and then use it in _.sortBy:

```
var counter = _.countBy(fruit_basket)
var result  = _(fruit_basket).uniq().sortBy(fruit => counter[fruit]).reverse().value()
```